# What to do with not enough training data?

Tags: neural-network

I have a problem that I don't have enough training data for my NN. It is trying to predict the result of a soccer game given the last games which I woulf say is a regression task. 
The training data are results of soccer games of the last 15 seasons (which are about 4500 games). Getting to new data would be hard and would take a lot of time.
What should I do now?

1. Is it good to duplicate the data?
2. Should I input randomized data? (Maybe noise but I'm not quite sure what that is)

If there is no way of creating more data,

3. I should probably turn up the learning rate right? (I have it sitting at 0.01 and the momentum at 0.9)
4. I am using mini batches consisting of 32 training datas in training. Since I don't have a lot of training I don't have a lot of mini batches. Should I stop using them?

Comment: Please consider adding what specifically you are trying to do with that data. Simply "throwing a neural network at a problem" is not a well-defined task. Is it classification? What are you trying to predict? How many different clubs/classes are there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start from the beginning: This is a very theoretical question and is not directly related to programming, which I recommend (in future) to post over at the [Data Science Stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com).

To go into your problem: 4500 samples is not as bad as it sounds, depending on the exact task at hand. Are you trying to predict the match results (i.e. which team is the winner?), are you looking for more specific predictions (across a lot of different, specific teams)?

If you can make sure that you have a reasonable amount of data *per class*, one can work with a number of samples lower than what you have. Simply duplicating the data will not help you much, since you are very likely to just overfit on the samples you are seeing, without much of an improvement; Or rather, you will get the same results as training over a longer period (since essentially you see every sample twice per epoch, instead of one).  
Again, what usually happens after long training periods is overfitting, so nothing gained here.

Your second suggestion is generally called *data augmentation*. Instead of simply copying samples, you alter them enough to make it look "different" to the network. But be careful! Data augmentation works well for some inputs, like images, since the change in input is significant enough to not represent the same sample, but still contains meaningful information about the class (a horizontally mirrored image of a cat still shows a "valid cat", unlike a vertically mirrored image, which is more unrealistic in the real world).
Essentially, it depends on your input features to determine where it makes sense to add noise. If you are only changing the results of the previous game, a minor change in input (adding/subtracting one goal at random) can significantly change the prediction you make.
If you slightly scramble ELO scores by a random number, on the other hand, the input value will not be too different, "but different enough" to use it as a novel example.

Turning up the learning rate is not a good idea, since you are essentially just letting the network converge *more* towards the specific samples. On the contrary, I would argue that the current learning rate is still too high, and you should certainly not increase it.
Regarding mini batches, I think [I have referenced this a million times now](https://twitter.com/ylecun/status/989610208497360896?lang=de), but **always consider smaller minibatches**. From a theoretical point of view, you are more likely to converge to a local minimum.

Comment: First of all... thanks for the good answer. It will be a regression task that should calculate the exact result (e.g. 2:1) and I want to give him the last 5 games as input so changing one of the results by one goal up or down should be ok right? How much noise should I use as training data?

Comment: Hm, maybe it would be more interesting to see whether you can predict the winner only, without the exact results, although I can see both working. Again, changing up/down is quite influencial, since 0:1 vs 1:0 are within your noise range, but still are the completely opposite result. Across five games this is arguably less influencial, but I would be careful and compare results with and without this.

Comment: I was thinking about changing one single number out of the 10... that would make one 2:1 e.g. to a 1:1. About the mini batches. Is a size of 32 ok? Or would smaller ones be better... What is the minimum because using only one data per mini batch would destroy it's purpose.

Comment: if you want to add additionnal noisy data (for augmentation), you must constraint the noise as dennliger (and you) said (for example, don't change the winner, maybe change one score only, not the two at the same time); I don't think it will improve your model so much, but as dennligner said, try with and without it. 32 batch sizes seems fine, I already see bigger batch size (128 !). But it depends on your machine.

Comment: All right. Thanks everyone looks like I got some testing to do